# How to read a single character in file using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file, character

In my file `data.txt`, I have a string `abcdefgh`. Now I want to take just 1 character without read whole string. How can I do this in MATLAB?

For example, I want to take the first character, I use `c = fscanf(data.txt, '%c');` and `c = textscan(data.txt, '%c');` but it read whole line in `data.txt`. I know that `c(1)` is my answer but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the number of characters that are read in using the third [input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html#inputarg_sizeA) to either `fscanf` or [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_N).

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

c = fscanf(fid, '%c', 1);
c = textscan(fid, '%c', 1);
```

You could also just use a lower-level function such as [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) to do this.

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
c = fread(fid, 1, '*char');
```

Comment: Yeah, it work for 1st character, but the problem happened when I read character i th or last character. I use c = fscanf(fid, '%c', len); ('len' is length of string in data.txt), it read whole string.

Comment: @VõHoàngTrọng Problems like this can be handled with random access streams. I happened to find the function [`fseek`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) in Matlab.